# nested promises, await and async

Tags: javascript

I got a main() function. This main function calls some functions and one of them is called lets say TEST(). TEST() calls TEST1(). This TEST1() calls let's say TEST2().
My Problem is that TEST2() makes an object, that has to be initialized, before my main() calls the next functions and my TEST() calls anything else.
I tried it like this but it doesn't work:

```
function main(){
    TEST1()
    //other functions
}

async function TEST() {
    await TEST1() // TEST1() and TEST2() should finish before 
    //going on with "some code"
    //some code
}

async function TEST1(something) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        //some stuff
        let newobject = await TEST2(somethingelse)
        resolve(newobject)
    });
}

function TEST2(somethingelse) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        //make object
        resolve(object)
        return object;
    });
}
```

TEST() worked already with TEST1(). But when adding the "asnyc" keyword to TEST1() and adding TEST2(), it doesnt work anymore. Probably because you maybe cannot use a promise in a async function?

Error is:

> "await" expression not allowed in this context.

Comment: `let newobject = await TEST2(somethingelse)` the enclosing function isn't `async`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to wrap the `newobject` in another `Promise`, you can directly return the result of `TEST2(somethingelse)` from the `TEST1` function as in an `async` context the return result is wrapped in a Promise implicitly.

You would also need to make your `main` function async as you want the `main` to wait:

> before my main() calls the next functions and my TEST() calls anything
>   else.

```js
async function main(){
    await TEST();
    console.log("Executing code after TEST in main");
}
async function TEST() {
     console.log("Before TEST1");
     await TEST1() 
     //some code
     console.log("Executing some other code");
     console.log("TEST finished");
}
    
async function TEST1(something) {
     console.log("TEST1 started");
     let newobject = await TEST2("somethingelse");
     console.log("TEST1 finished", newobject);
     return newobject;
}
    
function TEST2(somethingelse) {
      console.log("TEST2 started");
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          //make object
          const object = {"foo":somethingelse}
          resolve(object);
          console.log("TEST2 resolved");
      });
      
}
main();
```

Answer (score -1):

Prefer using async/await syntax. Much cleaner code.
And ditch the 'function' prefer using 'const' because it can be a function.
Also prefer using arrow functions. Io instead of const foo(value) { ... } should be const foo = (value) => { ... }.

```
const TEST = async () => {
     console.log("Before TEST1");
     await TEST1() 
     //some code
     console.log("Executing some other code");
     console.log("TEST finished");
}

const TEST1 = async (something) {
     console.log("TEST1 started");
     let result = await TEST2('somethingelse');
     console.log("TEST1 finished", result);
     return result;
}

const TEST2 = async (somethingelse) => {
      console.log("TEST2 started");
      const object = {"foo":somethingelse}
      // some async function here... use AWAIT for it.
      return object;

}
const main = async () => {
  await TEST();
}
```